# ajax and php code in the same page

Tags: php, ajax

I am doing form validation through ajax and php and it works fine.

Now there are two files i.e., ajax.html and codeValidate.php.

html form is in ajax and it checks the code validation using another file i.e. codeValidation.php.

Now I would like to have both in the same file and name it as Ajax.php. The code is as below.

```
//Ajax file

<html>
    <form id="form_submit">      
      <input id="coupon" name="coupon" type="text" size="50" maxlength="13" />
      <input id="btn_submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("form_submit").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); return false;});
      $("#btn_submit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
        var coupon = $("#coupon").val();  
        // validate for emptiness
        if(coupon.length < 1 ){ window.location.href="success.html"; }
        else{ 
          $.ajax({
            url: './codeValidate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {coupon: coupon},
            success: function(result){
              console.log(result);
              if(result){ window.location.href="success.html"; }
              else{ alert("Error: Failed to validate the coupon"); }
            }
          });     
        }
      });
    </script>
  </html>
```

My working php file :-

```
<?php 
  require("dbconfig.php");

  if(isset($_POST['coupon']) && !empty($_POST['coupon']) ){
    $coupon = trim($_POST['coupon']);        
    $checkcoupon = "SELECT couponCode FROM cc WHERE couponCode='".$coupon."'"; 
    $results_coupon = mysqli_query($dbc,$checkcoupon);    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results_coupon)) {   echo true; } 
    else { echo false; }   
  }
?>
```

Comment: Im not sure , but try this :- create a file  Ajax.php ,  copy both html and php code in it . Let your form be submitted to SELF . Now use include(.../file_path_to_Ajax.php);

Comment: Hi, I did that but did not work. Now without including it works, as I have given  url: './codeValidate.php'. In Ajax.php i changed it to  url: './Ajax.php' But did not work

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But it goes to success page without even  validating. As per this code it should go to success page either the field is blank or for the correct coupon code. But it goes to success page even the wrong coupon code is entered.

Comment: `$("#form_submit").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); return false;}); `    forgot `#form_submit` ?

Comment: Hi. thanks it works. I am php developer, never coded in jquery and ajax

Comment: sorry, it goes to codeValidate.php. I changed it to Ajax.php in the url part i.e., url: './codeValidate.php', but is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051548/ajax-to-php-on-the-same-page