# Making AJAX request and returning data on same page

Tags: php, ajax

Here's snippet from my code:
**page.php**

```
<input type="text" id="search_query" style="float: right" placeholder="Search" />
<div id="result"></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Date Published</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
        $query = $_POST['query'];
        $res = search_articles($query); // a function I have to query the database with SQL 'LIKE'
    } else {
        $res = view_articles(); // another function
    }
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] . ' ?>"/></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['author'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['date_published'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>
                <a href="?del=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a> | 
                <a href="?edit=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a>
            </td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

**and the ajax request:** (also in page.php)

```
function load_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        method: "POST",
        data: {query: query},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
$('#search_query').keyup(function () {
    var search = $(this).val();
    if (search != '') {
        load_data(search);
    } else {
        load_data();
    }
});
```

Basically, I have a search bar where the user can type anything and then the table where I'm showing the columns (taken from a database table) will change dynamically.

The code I have above is working fine but every time I type anything on the search bar, an exact copy of the page is being displayed (everything in my page gets displayed twice). Is there a way I can make the AJAX request return the table only and not the entire page? (without moving the entire code in a separate php file as I want to accomplish this in a single file)

I believe the problem is because I'm passing the data (which contains the whole page) to the #result div. I've tried looking for a solution and been tweaking my code for the last 3 hours or so but to no avail. I'm relatively new to these web technologies (God there are so many!) and I hope someone can help.

Comment: Any screen shot

Comment: better put the php where you send data in a seperate file. Or you have to exclude the rest (html) when `$_POST['query']` isset.

Comment: I've never set the "url" as empty

Comment: You should rearrange your code to accomplish what you want.It is not good to put all code in a single file

Comment: Hi Jeff, yeah I did that and it works but I really want to accomplish this without creating another php file. I was hoping there is some way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @MackProgramsAlot, I've been told that you have to set it to empty if you want to do it in a single file

Comment: There is a way, but it's a messy way. It'd be really no good design. Basicly wrap everything you don't want to get send into `if(!isset($_POST['query']) { }`

Comment: Hi @valbrux, yeah but it's just a few lines of code for viewing the data in a database table and I really don't want to create a separate file for that.

Comment: @GonFreaks interesting. Any reason why you wish to not have multiple pages?

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot, well I'm relatively new to web programming and I always try to create a single php file for each of my pages and another file that contains the functions for that particular page. I don't know I just find it a little tidier. But anyway, do you think there's nothing wrong in creating multiple files? like for example. articles.php, then articles_table.php?

Comment: Hi @SumanDey, here's the screenshots http://imgur.com/a/1o4D8

Comment: "I really want to accomplish this without creating another php file". Why, though? It seems an arbitrary requirement. It's a better, cleaner structure to separate out the functionality. Also, that way, the ajax endpoint is re-usable should you need it on another page.

Comment: Hi @ADyson yeah I guess I'll just put it in a separate file. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution posted here [Ajax to PHP on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051548/ajax-to-php-on-the-same-page)

Basically it suggest that you shouldn't *echo* rather than *exit()* your response. Otherwise, the remainder of the page is "loaded" again after the *if(isset...* is finished.