# Avoid form resubmission on reload with AJAX and Warning: Cannot modify header FIX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

The problem that I am facing here is that the form is resubmitted when the page is being refreshed. Now I know there are plenty of answers online for the problem I have stated above. But what is different in my problem is that I am using ajax to submit the form so the form is not redirecting and only a section of it is updated. Since I don't want the page to redirect therefore I can not use the post/redirect/get method.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" onsubmit="return submitdata();">
   <textarea maxlength="3000" id="profile-post" name="profile-post" placeholder="Write a post..." rows="3" cols="65" required></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Post">
 </form>
```

script:

```
 function submitdata()
        {
         var post=document.getElementById( "profile-post" );

         $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'page.php',
          data: {
           post:post
          }
         })
         };
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['profile-post'])){
  $post = $_POST['profile-post'];
  mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO make_post (post, time, date, user_id) VALUES ('$post', CURTIME(), CURDATE(), '$id_profile')"); 
  }
```

}

Is there any other way I can achieve the desired result which I couldn't find during my search online.

Thanks.

Comment: change `type="submit"` to   `type="button"`

Comment: ^ and move the `submitdata()` call to an onclick action on that button... or totally hijack the form so that you override the default action and have it return false on submission.

Comment: I don't get it, what is the problem exactly? I don't see how reloading this page would (re-) submit a form.

Comment: As @jeroen mentioned if you are using AJAX it shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @jeroen I am still in the learning phase I would say, so I cannot answer why is it happening. But it is.

Comment: @JYoThI This didn't work for me.

Comment: @CD001 I didn't get this.

Comment: what are you even returning form submitdata()?

Comment: @MayankSingh Nothing. I have tried return false that didn't do anything. also, my script and PHP are both in the same file as HTML could that be a problem?

Comment: but you are sending the post request to page.php, Or you mean that your html ,js and php is all in page.php so you have a single page only.

Comment: Yes. All the code is on the same page which is page.php. @MayankSingh
When I write PHP in the different page and make URL as different-page.php. the form is not submitting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051548/ajax-to-php-on-the-same-page Read this

Comment: @MayankSingh Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you type whatever you want into your form fetch it with jquery , send it to php page with ajax and query it into database afterwards dynamically insert it into ... table or something.
Most parts of your code or explanation is missing . this is the most i can give.

```
<form method="post">  
   <textarea maxlength="3000" id="profile-post" name="profile-post" placeholder="Write a post..." rows="3" cols="65" required></textarea>
   <button type="button" value="Post">
 </form>

$(document).ready(function(e){  

   var post = $('#profile-post').val();
$.ajax({
                    type:"POST" ,
                    data :{
                        'type' : 'post',
                        'id':  id,
                        'post' : post
                    },
                    url : '../allforms.php' //Php page to send data
                    }).success(function(data){
                        $('#profile-post').val('');
                        //Write code of whatever you want to load dynamically 
                               without loading
                    });

});
}
```

Please explain your desired result more clearly

Comment: I couldn't quite get your answer. My apologies. Could you kindly explain terms of my code or give me some link to understand this idea. Thank you.

Comment: Give me some timei will get back to you with a proper answer

Comment: I am submitting the form using Ajax so the form is not redirecting to any other page and only a division is being updated. Now when I refresh the page the form gets resubmitted. I don't want the form to resubmit on refresh. I hope I am being able to explain you clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding

```
header('location:page.php');
```

in my PHP file after form is submitted.
I thought this would redirect to the page.php and it will reload which I wanted to avoid and hence used ajax. But adding that line didn't reload the entire page.
I'm very thankful to everyone for taking out their time and answering to my question.
Also, I was getting an error when using header which was
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..
And it was fixed by adding

```
<?php ob.start();?>
```

and the beginning of the file.

I hope this could help anyone with similar problem. Thanks.